# React Navigation: Is it possible to goBack() or pop() with params?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation (V2) and I have a basic set up of screens like this:

```
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator
} from "react-navigation";

import DetailScreen from "../screens/DetailScreen";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import LoginScreen from "../screens/LoginScreen";
import SettingsScreen from "../screens/SettingsScreen";

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Detail: { screen: DetailScreen }
});

StackNavigator.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let drawerLockMode = "unlocked";
  if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
    drawerLockMode = "locked-closed";
  }
  return {
    drawerLockMode
  };
};

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  HomeStack: { screen: StackNavigator },
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
});

const Navigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  { LoginScreen, DrawerNavigator },
  { initialRouteName: "LoginScreen" }
);

export default Navigator;
```

While using my app the user ends up on the `DetailScreen`, makes some choices and is then supposed to go back to the `HomeScreen`. I want to pass params to the `HomeScreen` while going back. Unfortunately it seems like [`pop()`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#pop) and [`goBack()`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#goback-close-the-active-screen-and-move-back) do not accept any params.

How can I go back a screen and pass params while doing so?

Comment: You may pass a `func` from the `MainScreen` to `NavigatedScreen` in `setParams`, and call it before going back

Comment: @PritishVaidya that's a good idea! Is there a way to have it called AFTER the animation has finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**listeners**](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) for the screen and fire your refresh changes there.

`didFocus` - *the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition 
completed)*

```
// In your component
componentDidMount () {
    this._onFocusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', (payload) => {
      // Update the component (API calls here)
    });
}
```

Comment: That's awesome and already helps a lot! Is there a way to tell from which route the user came though? Because the event I would like to trigger after the animation should only occur if the user comes from a certain route.

Comment: The payload here should contain `state` and `lastState` which will give the `screen` details as mentioned [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#state-the-screen-s-current-state-route), or you may try it with the [screen tracking middleware](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/screen-tracking.html)

Comment: Thank you very much that helped me a lot!